# NancyFx Less and Super Simple View Engine

Tags: nancy

Is it possible to use [Cassette](https://github.com/ChrisMH/Cassette.Nancy) or [SquishIt](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/SquishIt-with-Nancy) in [NancyFx](http://nancyfx.org/) when using [Super Simple View Engine](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/The-Super-Simple-View-Engine)?

As i understand it SSVE does not have a way to place a bundle in its output. SSVE only provides simple conditional logic and regex output of the model properties

I'm partial to the style of SSVE and would rather use that over Razor if it's possible to do bundles and minification of CSS, Less and JavaScript, CoffeeScript.

Comment: I'd say yes. Then again I don't understand why you assume the view engine would matter to the compile/concat/minify process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSVE is a regex based view engine. If you look at the examples for [Cassette](https://github.com/ChrisMH/Cassette.Nancy) or [Squishit](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/SquishIt-with-Nancy) you see code such as:

```
@{
  Bundles.Reference("content");
  Bundles.Reference("scripts/app/page.js");
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Web App</title>
  @Bundles.RenderStylesheets()
</head>
<body>
  ...
  @Bundles.RenderScripts()
</body>
</html>
```

SSVE does not execute code blocks as such it has no method to execute the `@Bundles.RenderStylesheets()`

I was able to get around this be adding the output, in my case from [Squishit](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/SquishIt-with-Nancy) to the ViewBag using the NancyFx pipeline.

Here is a blog post with screenshots: http://eric.polerecky.com/css-and-javascript-bundles-super-simple-view-engine/